# how can i bind socket to ipv6 address?

Tags: c++, server, bind, ipv6

I am trying to port ipv4 applications to ipv6 but I can't bind the socket to the ipv6 address.

The problem is here:

```
err=bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
```

The `err` should be 0 but in this code it returns -1.  What is going wrong ?

```
SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting" << endl;
        return;
    }
    int err;
    // Bind the ip address and port to a socket
    sockaddr_in6 hint;
    hint.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    hint.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
    hint.sin6_port = htons(54000);
    hint.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    err=bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint)); //<======= here
```

Comment: What's `errno` being set to? (Hint: Use `perror()` or `strerror()` to get a nice human-readable error message)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than populate the `sockaddr_in6` manually, you can (and should) use [`getaddrinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) instead and let it allocate a properly filled `sockaddr_in6` for you, eg:

```cpp
int err;

SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    err = WSAGetLastError(); // or errno on non-Windows platforms...
    cerr << "Can't create a socket! Error " << err << ". Quitting" << endl;
    return;
}

// Bind the ip address and port to a socket

addrinfo hint = {};
hint.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST | AI_PASSIVE;
hint.ai_family = AF_INET6;
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

addrinfo *res;

err = getaddrinfo("::0", "54000", &hint, &res);
if (err != 0)
{
    cerr << "Can't get address to bind the socket! Error " << err << ". Quitting" << endl;
    closesocket(listening); // or close() on non-Windows platforms...
    return;
}

err = bind(listening, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
if (err == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    err = WSAGetLastError(); // or errno on non-Windows platforms...
    cerr << "Can't bind the socket! Error " << err << ". Quitting" << endl;
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    closesocket(listening); // or close() on non-Windows platforms...
    return;
}

freeaddrinfo(res);

...
```

Answer (score 2):

This might depend on your platform, but on Linux since 2.4 the `sockaddr_in6` structure also contains a `sin6_scope_id` member for defining the IPv6 scope, and since the variable `hint` is on the stack, it's got random data in it.

The IPv6 scope describes what kind of address it is: unicast, multicast, link local, and a few others, and I have only a drive-by knowledge of them. But if there's garbage in there, it could be a thing.

Recommend ruling this out as an issue by either hard-setting `sin6_scope_id` to zero, or (better) just zero out the entire `sockaddr_in6` structure before assigning stuff to it; I've long done this with my `sockaddr_in` variables just to be sure I didn't end up with junk I didn't want.

```
memset(&hint, 0, sizeof hint);
```

And yes, the `errno` is really important.

Comment: Or instead of memset you can use struct initialization to zero.