# IPv6 client can't connect to IPv6 server

Tags: c++, ipv6

My program is client server IPv6. the client can't make connection to the server? The client and server must use loop-back address
the problem in this code its can't connect to the server

```
   SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
  {
    cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return;
 }

   sockaddr_in6 hint;
hint.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
hint.sin6_port = htons(port);
hint.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
// Connect to server
int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() 
   << endl;
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client TCP socket cannot `connect()` to `in6addr_any`.  A TCP server can `bind()` to `in6addr_any` so it can then `listen()` on all available local IPv6 network interfaces with a single `SOCKET`.  But the client must `connect()` to a real IPv6 address that the server is actually listening on (such as `in6addr_loopback` if the client is running on the same machine as the server. Your server can use `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()` to discover what its local IP addresses actually are that are valid for the client to `connect()` to).

Also, you need to zero out the `sockaddr_in6` struct completely.  `sockaddr_in6` has `sin6_flowinfo` and `sin6_scope_id` fields that you are not populating, so they will have random values from the stack.  `sin6_scope_id` in particular will affect `connect()`'s ability to use the correct network interface to connect to the server.

```cpp
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

sockaddr_in6 hint = {};
hint.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
hint.sin6_port = htons(port);
inet_pton(AF_INET6, "server IPv6 address here", &(hint.sin6_addr));

// Connect to server
int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
...
```

Consider using `getaddrinfo()` instead.  Let the OS allocate a properly-populated `sockaddr_in6` for you, which you can then pass as-is to `connect()` (similarly to how I explained to you in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531087/) for `bind()`).

```cpp
addrinfo hint = {};
hint.ai_family = AF_INET6;
hint.ai.socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

addrinfo *res;

err = getaddrinfo("server hostname or IPv6 address here", "server port here", &hint, &res);
if (err != 0)
{
    cerr << "Can't get address to connect, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

SOCKET sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// Connect to server
int connResult = connect(sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    closesocket(sock);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

freeaddrinfo(res);
...
```